# Filename Case issue with over WebDav

Tags: samba, webdav, case-sensitive

We are accessing SAMBA shared directory from a Windows Client with WebDav client WebDrive. But we are having the issue that it is showing same contents in both the directories ( data/ & Data/ ) though they are entirely different.

I know this is because of Windows Filesystem being case insensitive and Linux being Case Sensitive.

is there any solution for this?

We had the same issue when viewed through the SAMBA mounted directory but we solved it by editing the SMB.conf as said in the following link

[Does Samba work well with Windows when case-sensitive names are enabled?](https://serverfault.com/questions/70570/does-samba-work-well-with-windows-when-case-sensitive-names-are-enabled/322984)

Please help to solve this when accessed from the WebDav

Comment: NTFS is case sensitive. Windows is not (by default).

Answer (score 3):

Rename the directory.

Trying to force Windows to play nice with a case-sensitive filesystem might be workable in a very narrow set of circumstances, but trying to get it to work correctly in all use cases is an exercise in futility.

It may be worth a shot to enable case sensitivity in the kernel, but beware - this is likely to break applications that expect case insensitivity:

```
Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel
Value: obcaseinsensitive
Data: 0x0
```

Why would you want to have that as a file organization scheme, anyway?

> "Hey, Paul, that file's under the data directory."
>
> "Huh?  I don't see it there.."
>
> "No, no, not capital-D-lowercase-A-lowercase-T-lowercase-A.. it's in capital-D-lowercase-A-capital-T-capital-A, I thought that was obvious from the fact that it's a TPS report!"

Answer (score 0):

I also use WebDrive and it appears to be a bug in WebDrive. However, it works when I connect using the standard Windows WebDAV client. Have you tried NetDrive?
BTW, I use the BarracudaDrive WebDAV server.